# Find Latest on the latest date

Tags: sql, max

I have a table the contains employees names, a date when they have booked a job and the time of that booking what I and wanting to find the latest date and latest time on that date against each employee.

| Employee | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 09/05/21 | 08:00 |
| Matt | 08/05/21 | 07:00 |
| Matt | 09/05/21 | 07:00 |
| Paul | 08/05/21 | 06:59 |
| Mark | 10/05/21 | 10:20 |

Expected result

| Employee | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | 09/05/21 | 07:00 |
| Paul | 08/05/21 | 06:59 |
| Mark | 10/05/21 | 10:20 |

Cheers

Comment: What have you done so far? and why do you store date and time seperately?

Comment: Please mention your dbms name with version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee order by date desc, time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  It is usually better to store date and time in a *single* column rather than in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table yourtable (Employee varchar(50),Date date, Time time);
 insert into yourtable values('Mark',   '09/05/21', '08:00');
 insert into yourtable values('Matt',   '08/05/21', '07:00');
 insert into yourtable values('Matt',   '09/05/21', '07:00');
 insert into yourtable values('Paul',   '08/05/21', '06:59');
 insert into yourtable values('Mark',   '10/05/21', '10:20');

 with EmployeeLatestBooking as
 (
    select employee,date,time,row_number()over(partition by employee order by date ,time )rn
    from yourtable
 )
 select Employee,date,time from EmployeeLatestBooking where rn=1
 GO
```

Outupt:

| Employee | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 2021-09-05 | 08:00:00.0000000 |
| Matt | 2021-08-05 | 07:00:00.0000000 |
| Paul | 2021-08-05 | 06:59:00.0000000 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=211af358335525ecfb6da054dc18da9f)*